# Would driving transformer with MCU's GPIO cause durability issue?

Tags: microcontroller, transformer, gpio

For making isolated power supply, I would like to drive a transformer  with two GPIO's of a MCU. 
The center tab of the primary will be connected to Vcc. And each end of the primary will be toggled between Vcc and Gnd using GPIO alternatively.

The secondary side the center tab will be connected to the Gnd and each end of the secondary will feed a diode bridge which will be connected to the switching regulator for isolated power.

My question is, would the back noise from the the transformer damage the MCU over time or even cause the MCU to mal-function all together?

Thank you

Comment: As motoprogger said, this is not viable as V_undriven will exceed Vdd (Vcc). You can do this using two transistors - bipolar or FET, at little cost. The undriven transistor collector or drain with rise to about 2 x Vdd with no problems.  | If you use MOSSFETS you may be able to do this with 2 x MOSFETS and NO other parts. Switching frequency needs to be low enough with MOSFETS to ensure that gate drive capacitance can be charged / discharged fast enough.|  Leakage inductance may cause short duration high voltage spikes at switching edges. These can be easily managed with separate transistors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the only realistic option open to the OP - adding two MOSFETs to control the transformer primary: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXZm4j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transformer primary CANNOT be driven from GPIO pins directly - think about the transformer primary - the average voltage across its input terminals must be zero and if one line is pulled down to 0V, the other transformer line rises to Vcc x 2 and destroys the GPIO pin. Using FETs overcomes this problem because the FETs turn off to an open circuit and allow the disconnected transformer line to rise to Vcc x 2.

Comment: Yet another option is to drive the transformer in half-bridge or bridge configuration directly with GPIO pins if the MCU outputs can source enough current.

Comment: @motoprogger that would work for low power demands.

Comment: Just to be clear, if i drive one GPIO-1 to VDD and GPIO-0 to GND in my original configuration, the GPIO-1's VDD output will shorted to transformer's 2VDD on the same node?

Comment: @jay imagine the centre tap as a pivot point for a see-saw. If you sit on one end, the othe end rises twice as high but your idea prevents it doing so.

Comment: @Andyaka How about removing the center tab connection all together so that GPIO sinks and sources the current?

Comment: @jay that works just fine and this was a suggestion that I endorsed on another answer. In effect it becomes a mini H bridge but, use low fwd volt drop schottky diodes like you would on a h bridge and don't expect great performance

Comment: It wasn't said which uC was being used, but for example the GPIOs on most PIC uCs can source/sink up to 25mA. If you need any kind of power out of this transformer, you're stuck with bipolar or MOSFET drivers.

Comment: @rdtsc I think you miss the point - to drive a centre tapped transformer requires open collector/drain outputs that can withstand twice the supply voltage and this doesn't take account of fly-back voltages due to leakage inductance in the transformer. This type of drive MUST have open collector/drains - there is no option to drive them with a push-pull signal.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to add two more mosfets, per side, one npn and matching pnp to form a push pull circuit. The primary coil of the transformer would have to be rated at 20 volts and have a very high resistance, meaning a lot of windings as well, for resonance, I would add a capacitor across from the center tap to each side, and, it may be advisable to buy a variable air capacitor and oscilloscope for testing coil resonance to make home made transformers if you aren't using a prebuilt xfrmr. The secondary would need to have the same orientation, grounded outer ends and a center tap for the correct transformation.

The mosfet has to have a high enough gate voltage so it turns all the way on otherwise you will have a partially on condition, burning up the  junction and the insulative layer of the gate will fail early.

Here is basically what happens. You are using a square wave, and, like the sinewave, you have a peak to peak voltage. If you have a 12 volt "sine", the voltage is actually 24 volts peak to peak. The voltage between the gates of the high and low must have at the least 20 volts difference in potential depending on the mosfet used.

If you use a logic gate mosfet, then this may work but it is extremely dependent of the signal you are driving the circuit with.

I would use an op amp like the 741 to deliver a signal from the fgen that will amplify the signal from a 5 or 9 volt signal to a 20 volt signal, then, combine what I said with your circuit, a push pull, so, when the logic is high, the other junction mosfet pulls the logic completely low instead of leaving it at .6-2.6 volts where the gate may be partially conducting and heating or burning the mosfet. (what most everybody is seeing here is the coil, but, they fail to see that you are energizing a coil by placing the feed at the center tap and the negative will be coming from the transistor. The problem is that the transformer coil isn't usually meant to be driven in two directions, only one, which you have a negative feeding back from each end, and, you will need to add snubbers as the mosfets are sensitive to back emf which you will end up with as sharp source pulses from a pulse train will produce a high level if your coil has a high impedance and, of course, you will need a good sized coil not for the transistor to result in a shorted condition of like 2-5 ohms or so, while it isn't a good idea to have too much, but, the coil needs to handle the voltage being driven into it. Your coil will need to have a negative on one side, and the positive on the other, and, the core from the primary to the secondary will have to have only one polarity of flux as you are creating two, you have a negative feeding back from each end, causing a monopolar core with south poles on each end and the north in the middle. The secondary must be would in the same manner, but, opposite way, and, you'd eliminate the necessary flux from one side to transform to the other as you'll need a north and a south on the ends, as it will oscillate N-S, back and forth as the wave oscillates. The wave you have is oscillating, but, you need a secondary with the center tap too for this to operate correctly.

In theory, you have the right idea, but, most mosfets won't switch on and off with a square wave like you need, so, you will get an "on" and it will stay on burning the coil up and possibly the mosfets, or, it won't even turn on. The mosfet is a switch, and to use it as a switch, you'll have to raise the gate voltage to the highest possible "rms" gate voltage that it's rated for in it's data sheet.

For instance, if you use an IRF540, the p channel matching mosfet for the push pull would be the irf9540 . I certainly would check on the data sheets from the manufacturer to find the optimum push pull circuit and do not read up on the gate threshold because this is just enough to start the conducting and turn the mosfet on. It may not be enough to turn it on all the way, but, it will need a neg or low logic to shuit it back off, and, this is what the push pull does. If the signal gen you are using sends a pulsed input which was only 8 volts, and the push pull wasn't used, the gate voltage rests at like 2.6 volts, keeping the mosfet on dangerously low and heating it up since it isn't conducting all the way, making it leak through the resistant layer and of course heating a lot to damage it early.

If a push up resistor is used to bring the voltage up to a higher level, then, it may be safe to do, but, now you have to bring the level back down when you need to , adding another mosfet , p channel is the way, as well, a pull down resistor between the gate line and ground to bring voltage close to zero to pull that one on while the signal's line is under the hot state and it makes the p channel transistor conduct, feeding the lower level of the signal, back and forth, as you wish to make it happen.

It is all written in the data sheet how to do this and it must be done with the correct resistors as there is no protection in your circuit, and you'll need resistors, diodes, etc.

It will work once you see what has to be done and it should teach you more about the mosfet and the reason why it won't work, and why using this as an alternative will work.

Read up on Mosfets online, start at really early education levels since you are in question with simple transistor technology.

Good Luck!
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Your MCU is likely to have protective diodes between outputs and Vcc. If the center tap is at Vcc, and one end is pulled to GND, the other end (disconnected) will be at 2Vcc for the whole half period. The protective diode would short that half-winding, and your MCU's output would come to current limit very soon. So your circuit is not going to work at all.

What regards the inrush current at switching moments, it'll be about the same as your transformer's zero load primary current (because of the winding's self-inductance). Check your MCU's datasheet if it can stand that.

Comment: It's generally a very bad idea to rely on the MCU's protection for operation of your circuit.

Comment: @JohnU the MCUs protection would inhibit the operation of the circuit - as motoprogger says, with the configuration planned by the OP, the undriven output will rise (and must rise) to twice Vcc.